# org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner not found

Tags: java, mockito, powermock

Tried adding deps per [Power Mockito showing error for org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50063992/power-mockito-showing-error-for-org-powermock-modules-junit4-common-internal-imp) but no luck.

build.gradle reads:

```
....
testCompile "junit:junit:4.12"
testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.5'
testCompile 'javax:javax-persistence:2.1.0.v201304241213'
testCompile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.5'
testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-common:1.6.5'
testCompile group: 'javax.ws.rs', name: 'jsr311-api', version: '1.1.1'
testCompile group: 'javax', name: 'javaee-api', version:'7.0'
....
```

I go to run tests locally with @ RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) and I get this error:

```
Error:(26, 25) java: cannot access org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner class file for org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner not found
```

Anyone else seen this before?

Comment: Just wondering: what version of Java are you using? And of course, my usual two cent: don't use PowerMock(ito) unless you have to. The only good reason to use it: testing legacy code that cant be tested otherwise.

Comment: 1.8.  Yeah, PM kinda blows.  Appreciate the feedback.